# Shake wx.Dialog after validation fails

Tags: modal-dialog, wxpython

I have a `wx.Dialog` with a custom validation process that runs after the OK button is pressed. If the validation fails I would like to shake the `wx.Dialog` to let users know that something is wrong with the given input.

Is there something like this implemented in wxPython?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way, would be activate a `wx.Timer` with a short interval that moves the dialog's position, when the processing fails.

Something like this:

```
import wx

class Busy(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Busy", size= (420,240))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Processing..................", pos=(120,20))
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self.panel,size=(300,25),pos=(80,80))
        self.livelabel = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Time to live:", pos=(80,110))
        self.lltime = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="10", pos=(160,110))
        self.closeButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Cancel", pos=(180,160))
        self.closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnQuit)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.lifetimer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnLifeTimer, self.lifetimer)
        self.lifetimer.Start(1000)
        self.life = 10
        self.Show()
        self.alt_pos = False

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        curr_pos_x, curr_pos_y = self.GetPosition()
        if self.alt_pos:
            self.Move(curr_pos_x+2, curr_pos_y)
            self.alt_pos = False
        else:            
            self.Move(curr_pos_x+-2, curr_pos_y)            
            self.alt_pos = True

    def OnLifeTimer(self, evt): #Update time to live
        self.gauge.Pulse()
        self.life -= 1
        self.lltime.SetLabelText(str(self.life))
        if self.timer.IsRunning() or self.life > 0:
            return
        else:
            self.label.SetLabel("Timed Out")
            self.timer.Start(50)

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.lifetimer.Stop()
        self.result_text = None
        self.EndModal(False)

app = wx.App()
dlg = Busy(parent = None)
result = dlg.ShowModal()
print (result)
if result:
    print (dlg.result_text)
else:
    print ("Dialog Cancelled")
dlg.Destroy()
```

[image]